# Is Pygame click event compatible with the PITFT, or Is there a kind of "special" event made for it?

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I've made a pygame GUI interface with buttons who are activated when the user click on them. The GUI works well when I'm using my real mouse but when I run the GUI on the [PITFT](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1601), buttons don't respond to clicks ( even if I use a harder material than my finger like a stylus ).

Are Pygame click event compatible with the PITFT or are there a kind of "special" event made for it?

Here is the current mouse event I use in my code:

```py
def run(self):
    """Lance la boucle principale pour gérer les événements"""
    while True:
        event = pygame.event.wait()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1 and not self.keep_level_2:
        self.click(event.pos)

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
        self.release(event.pos)
```

I search on the internet and found that in order to use the PITFT, you need to add the following lines:

```py
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'fbcon'
os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDEV"] = "/dev/input/touchscreen"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDRV"] = "TSLIB"
```

So I've tried adding them but the touchscreen is still not responding.

Also, when to program run, I can't quit it ( CTRL+C and escape don't work ).

Note: My code is not running in python3.

Comment: From what you have posted, you need to set the mouse device and the mouse driver for pygame to correctly capture the mouse. Where have you added these lines?

Comment: I also tried to lower the resolution of my pygame window so it doesn't appears in fullscreen ( so i can try to quit by clicking the exit button of the window ) but that doesn't work too... In fact, the pygame window stay in fullscreen:/

Comment: And how can i add those drivers ? :) I had these lines at the beginings ( just after the "imports lines" )

Comment: I have this screen working with pygame and have set the same `os.environ` lines that you have. It's not immediately clear to me what the issue is. I didn't test for `event.button`. Have a look at my code here: https://github.com/elParaguayo/RPI-Info-Screen/blob/PiTFT/default.py

Comment: @elParaguayo Did you use the custom raspbian Kernel "ready to burn image" or did you follow the guide inn order to install it on your current raspian ? Maybe they have different driver's name.

Comment: I followed the guide on the Adafruit site. Did you follow the touchscreen calibration instructions? Did they work for you?

Comment: I just install the ready to go image of raspian ( here https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/software-installation ) and the touchscreen works perfectly when my pygame windows in not launched.

Comment: I've just test my touchscreen with "evtest" and it seems to work proprely so i really don't know where to problem is comming from :/

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is you're doing a button up, button down methond.

I get my pygame GUI to work by going...

```
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if x+w > mouse_pos[0] > x and y+h > mouse_pos[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
```

HOWEVER for me this creates other issues because I don't think that 1 tap on the touch screen is a SMOOTH single click. What happens for me is that my button will click, then it will for no apparent reason do a second 'click' (I think because of 'fuzz' in the click).

As a result, my 'on' buttons turn on (they work perfectly) and then they turn off. Not quite sure what to do about that yet, but hopefully it gets your project working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your /dev/input/touchscreen is "linked" to the right module?
Check evtest /dev/input/touchscreen and check if it does anything when using the screen, or the keyboard, or the mouse!

If this is happening you should follow the install procedure again.