# Raspberry pi Pygame issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspbian

I have a Kedei V6.3 touchscreen for a raspberry pi and I'm using raspbian 8 Jessie and a raspberry pi 1B. My touchscreen is running and I'm trying to install a UI from gitHub: https://github.com/garthvh/pitftmenu i have installed it, but when i try to run it it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/pitftmenu/menu_kali-1.py", line 11, in <module>
    pygame.display.init()
pygame.error: Unable to open mouse
```

I tried to run it regularly and as root.i have downloaded my OS from here: http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html and the software works, but if i try sudo apt-get upgrade, the touchscreen stops working, so i cannot update it and i would really like to run that UI

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to better format error message

Comment: did you try `PyGame` without any extensions to see if mouse is working ? Did you try with attached mouse ?

Comment: did you use Google to find help ? With Google I found this ["mouse position in pygame with piTFT"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131889&p=879999) and this ["PyGame and touchscreen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875682/pygame-and-touchscreen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, I've found the answer to the problem and it's pretty simple, all i had to do is to run it in raspberry pi Desktop. I was trying to run it through SSH and was hoping that it would show up, but it turns out, you cannot run it in ssh.